# how to dump all setting of handsontable instance and save to server(not save data in table to server)

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I want to achieve：
One user creates handsontable using client browser: to insert or delete some columns, edit column headers, fix some rows or columns by context menu for other users to fill. So I need to save handsontable structure to server.

The following code initialize a 3*3 handsontable with `contextMenu: true`

```
var
    $$ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  },
  container = $$("example"),
  hot;
  
  Handsontable.dom.addEvent(createtable, "click", function() {
      hot = new Handsontable(container, {
      rowHeaders: true,
      colHeaders: true,
      dropdownMenu: true,
      startRows: 3,
      startCols: 3,
      contextMenu: true,
      licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
    })
  })
```

Then I set column A readonly by context menu.
Using following code get `columns` option. I expect the result is `[{readonly: true},{},{}]`, but it is `undefined`

```
  Handsontable.dom.addEvent(gettablesetting, "click", function() {
    console.log(hot.getSettings().columns)
  })
```

how to dump all options of handsontable instance and save to server for other users to fill.

[jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/aHero1588/0eLmraub/29/)

Comment: Hi. You never define `columns` property. It seems logical then that the result in undefined.